# Android иконки с большим разрешением для всех устройств

Tags: android

У меня есть пак иконок, все 512х512, т.е в хорошем качестве, я закинул их в drawable и работаю с ними, тестил приложение на трех устройствах, вроде бы всё нормально работает. Хорошее ли это решение - просто использовать для всех устройств одни и те же иконки с одним разрешением? Или скажем слабые устройства из-за этого будут глючить и мне придется делать разные разрешения иконок, копируя их в drawable-xhdpi ... и т.д

Второй вопрос:
Принципиальна ли разница - помещу я иконки в mipmap или drawable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если бы все было так просто и гладко - зачем вообще разработчики бы заморачивались на тему плотности экранов? Ось сама растягивает\сжимает изображение, если оно слишком маленькое\большое для экрана конкретного телефона, но это к слову, забирает некоторые ресурсы - и для списков с большим количеством элементов это может стать проблемой нехватки ресурсов, значит и лагов.

Ко всему прочему - некоторые экраны ось попросту не сможет подогнать под нужные размеры, либо они будут смотреться с артефактами\квадратиками\неровностями - иначе говоря, последствия могут быть самыми разными и если рассчитываете на широкую аудиторию - то непременно, для каждой плотности экрана необходимо делать свои иконки.

Насчет второго вопроса - насколько я читал, мипмап создана больше для структуризации - это ровно такая же директория, как и Drawable. Каждый предмет должен лежать на своем месте, а не тусоваться в куче других предметов - пускай и похожих. Это CamelCase вашего проекта. Гайдлайн.

UPD к вопросу о цифрах, официальная документация гласит:

> Alternative drawables
>
> Figure 4. Relative sizes for bitmap drawables that support each
> density.
>
> Almost every application should have alternative drawable resources
> for different screen densities, because almost every application has a
> launcher icon and that icon should look good on all screen densities.
> Likewise, if you include other bitmap drawables in your application
> (such as for menu icons or other graphics in your application), you
> should provide alternative versions or each one, for different
> densities.
>
> Note: You only need to provide density-specific drawables for bitmap
> files (.png, .jpg, or .gif) and Nine-Patch files (.9.png). If you use
> XML files to define shapes, colors, or other drawable resources, you
> should put one copy in the default drawable directory (drawable/).
>
> To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you
> should follow the 3:4:6:8:12:16 scaling ratio between the six
> generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable
> that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screens, all the different
> sizes should be:
>
> 36x36 (0.75x) for low-density 48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
>
> 72x72 (1.5x) for high-density 96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
>
> 144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density 192x192 (4.0x) for
> extra-extra-extra-high-density (launcher icon only; see note above)

Заодно прикреплю отдельный [гайд по иконкам](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)

Comment: А какие размеры соответствуют папкам в drawable? В интернете нашел
LDPI  36×36.
MDPI 48×48.
TVDPI 64×64.
HDPI 72×72.
XHDPI 96×96.
XXHDPI 144×144.
XXXHDPI 192×192.
Верное распределение?

Comment: @ЯктенсТид должно быть верное, ну у меня с этим заморачивается дизайнер, так что в цифрах не так уж глубоко подкован :)

Comment: Просто в интернете не могу найти информацию с советами, какого размера иконку лучше в какую папку пихать

Comment: @ЯктенсТид цифры были правильные, обновил ответ